# wpf how to add multiple tabcontrols to one window

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

So, right now I have tabs to the left. However, I want tabs at the top of my screen to, because those are different controls I want to implement. I tried just adding another tabcontrol in my grid, but the layout gets completely screwed up and none of the tabs work anymore.

Any solutions?

```
<Window x:Class="Berichtensysteem.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Berichtensysteem"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Mailclient" Height="auto" Width="auto"
        >

        <Grid Height="400" Width="600">

        <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" >
            <TabItem Header="Inbox" Height="30">
                <TabItem.Content>
                    <ListView  Name="inbox" BorderThickness="2">
                        <ListView.View >
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="From" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding from}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Subject" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding subject}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Content" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding content}" />
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </TabItem.Content>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Verzonden items" Height="30">
                <TabItem.Content>
                    <ListView  Name="sentitems" BorderThickness="2">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="From" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding from}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Subject" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding subject}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Content" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding content}" />
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </TabItem.Content>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Verwijderde Items" Height="30"
                     >
                <TabItem.Content>
                    <ListView  Name="deleteditems" BorderThickness="2">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="From" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding from}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Subject" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding subject}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Content" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding content}" />
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </TabItem.Content>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: Can you create a sketch of what you want to achieve? (ProTip - head over to [ux.stackexchange] and use the tools built into asking/answering).

Comment: Multiple tab controls work just fine. What did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple tab controls work - you just need to now how you want them hierarchically ordered. 
For example, this XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid Height="400" Width="600">
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Folders" Height="30">
            <TabItem.Content>
                <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" >
                  <TabItem Header="Inbox" Height="30">
                     <TabItem.Content>
                            <ListView  Name="inbox" BorderThickness="2">
                                <ListView.View >
                                    <GridView>
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="From" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding from}" />
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="Subject" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding subject}" />
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="Content" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding content}" />
                                    </GridView>
                                </ListView.View>
                            </ListView>
                        </TabItem.Content>
                    </TabItem>
                    <TabItem Header="Verzonden items" Height="30">
                        <TabItem.Content>
                            <ListView  Name="sentitems" BorderThickness="2">
                                <ListView.View>
                                    <GridView>
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="From" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding from}" />
                                      <GridViewColumn Header="Subject" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding subject}" />
                                      <GridViewColumn Header="Content" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding content}" />
                                 </GridView>
                             </ListView.View>
                            </ListView>
                      </TabItem.Content>
                 </TabItem>
                    <TabItem Header="Verwijderde Items" Height="30"
                 >
                        <TabItem.Content>
                            <ListView  Name="deleteditems" BorderThickness="2">
                                <ListView.View>
                                    <GridView>
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="From" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding from}" />
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="Subject" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding subject}" />
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="Content" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding content}" />
                                    </GridView>
                                </ListView.View>
                            </ListView>
                        </TabItem.Content>
                    </TabItem>
                </TabControl>
                </TabItem.Content>
            </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Second Tab">
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

will look like that:

[image]

Comment: Ahh, they key was nesting them. Thanks